# Parse value from string with structure "key=value"

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like this:

```
SUBJECT=Some text here\r\n
VALUE=19355711\r\n
RCV_VALUE=2851404175\r\n
RESULT=1\r\n
CNCODE=0\r\n
KEY1=1\r\n
KEY2=2
```

Now I need to get the values of RCV_VALUE and RESULT from this string. The position of these keys in the string may vary. They can also be at the beginning or/and at the end of the string.

Value of RESULT I must get as `int`, and value of RCV_VALUE I must get as `string`.

What is the best way to get the values of these keys regardless of their position in the string?

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with @zzzz's vowel keys, but, what _have_ you tried so far?

Comment: is it  complete string ? \r and \n are pasrt of string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best bet is a regular expression

```
var regex=new Regex(@"RCV_VALUE=(?<value>\d+)");
var match=regex.Match(inputString);
var rcv_value=int.Parse(match.Groups["value"].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using an regular expression easily enough, as per the example below.

```
Regex expr = new Regex(@"^(?<Key>.*)=(?<Value>.*)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

var m = expr.Match("SUBJECT=Some text here\r\n");
var key = m.Groups["Key"].Value;
var value = m.Groups["Value"].Value;
// or 
var kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(m.Groups["Key"].Value, m.Groups["Value"].Value);
```

Or alternatively if you do not want to use a regular expression you can split the string using the `=` as a delimiter and then parse the values in pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Use string [spilt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to split it into multiple lines, and then loop over the array. After this i would use [indexof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) and either substring or string remove to get the parts i want.

This all being said, this questions smells of "do my work for me". I would recommend going to www.codeproject.com and learn the basics.

Comment: "this questions smells of "do my work for me" - Why do you think so? I didn't ask to make code for me. I just asked for advice.

Comment: Because its so generic, leaves me with the impression you in the very early stages of learning to code or have a spesifc problem that you want fixed. This combined with that your questions does not show that you made a effort to fix it you self.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Now, when I understood what I must use regular expressions, I will learn all information about regular expressions, string and many other things.

Comment: You dont have to solve it with regex, there are a million ways of doing it. But seems the SO community preferes it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var RCV_VALUE = Regex.Match(myString, "RCV_VALUE=(\d+)").Groups[1].Value
```